# which cone is used for conic section?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

There are a lot of equations for a cone, such as

1. $x^2 + y^2=z^2$
2. $(x-a)^2+ (y-b)^2=((z-c)R)^2$
3. $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{c^2}= \dfrac{z^2}{c^2}$
4. $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 +2fyz + 2gzx + 2hxy=0$

But then comes this equation that I found in the book *Maths in Minutes*.

> $$x^2 + y^2= |z|$$

The book says that this is the cone that is used for the conic section, and this equation is slightly different because the z variable is not squared.

When I input the equation in the 3d plot it shows this

[image]

And the equation with $z^2$ gives us a graph like this:

[image]

> Which one is suitable for the conic section?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=z$ (no need for absolute value) is the equation of a paraboloid as you can see it on the representation. It is definitely note a cone (you indeed need $z^2$ on the RHS). Your book "maths in minutes" is maybe too much in a hurry...

Comment: As mentioned, the surface is a [paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid), not a cone, so there's some kind of error here. Maybe the book intended $$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ Anyway ... It's perhaps worth noting (although this is certainly *not* what your book was indicating) that a paraboloid —indeed, any [quadric surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric)— has the property that its intersections with a plane are still members of the conic section family (ellipses, parabolas, hyperbolas).

Comment: you mean i can get the conic section from a  paraboloid?

Comment: @ALvees: *"you mean i can get the conic section from a paraboloid?"* ... You *can*, but for properly understanding the unified geometry of conics (for instance, with [Dandelin spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres) and whatnot), using a proper cone is key. ... Nevertheless, it's a fact that planes cut quadrics in these same kinds of curves. *Very* roughly speaking, it's because quadrics are degree-$2$ eqns in $x$ and $y$, and planes are degree-$1$, so their intersection is at most a degree-$(2\times 1)$ curve; and we *know* all degree-$2$ curves are "conics".

Comment: To be clear: the intersection of a plane and paraboloid (or any quadric surface) is a conic—perhaps degenerate—but if you use something other than a cone, you might not be able to generate all of the conic. There’s no way to produce a hyperbola with a plane-paraboloid intersection, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intersect a cone, or a paraboloid, or a hyperboloid, or a sphere, or an ellipsoid with a plane, then the curve of intersection, seen as a curve in the intersecting plane, is the solution to a quadratic equation. And those are always conic sections (unless they are degenerate, e.g. the union of two lines, or a single point).

In particular, you can use any cone you want, and get the same qualitative results. The actual resulting equations will be different, of course, and some cone equations might be easier to use for calculation than others.